# jQuery replace attr href with string values

Tags: jquery, html, string, href, attr

I try to replace some href attributes with the IDs of some DIVs.

I have a list with (e.g.) three links and without href values like:

```
<ul id="Downloads">
    <li><a href="">Some content 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Some content 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Some content 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also have some DIVs on the same page with unique IDs in a container:

```
<div id="DownloadsContent">
    <div id="221">Some content</div>
    <div id="325">Some content</div>
    <div id="124">Some content</div>
</div>
```

I want to get the IDs of the three DIVs and set them as href attributes to the three links like:

```
<li><a href="#221">Some content 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#325">Some content 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#124">Some content 3</a></li>
```

I tried it with the .map and .each function, but with my current attempt, I get links like `<a href="221,325,124"></a>` – so the href attribute is replaced with the whole string.

Here's my approach:

```
var id = $('#DownloadsContent > div').map(function() { return this.id }).get();

$.each(id,function() {
    $("#Downloads li a").attr('href', id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr` method.

```
var $divs = $('#DownloadsContent > div');

$('#Downloads a').attr('href', function(i, c){
   return '#' + $divs.eq(i).attr('id')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AG2LQ/

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I used this code to add the hash sign:

$('#Downloads a').attr('href', function(i, c){
   return '#' + $('#DownloadsContent > div').eq(i).attr('id');
})

Answer (score 0):

You need to use THIS to iterate, and choose a different  every time (i in this case):

```
$.each(id,function(i) {
   $("#Downloads li a").eq(i).attr('href', this);
});
```

**(Editted thanks to comment)**

Comment: I think you want this instead if item, and skip the parameter.